# Batch requests to GCP Compute using Golang client library

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-go-client

Is it possible to perform batch requests using the Google API Client Library for Go?

More precisely, I'd like to delete some disks; it would be great if I could avoid a request for each disk.

The batch request feature I'm referring to:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/batch

The client library I'm using:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client

It seems there's also another client library, but without support for the Compute Engine, only metadata (?):
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i think it can be done since we can dlete a disk using API call.
A batch request consists of multiple API calls combined into one HTTP request, which can be sent to the batchPath specified in the [API discovery document](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis). The default path is /batch/api_name/api_version.

[Example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch#example) take a look on the Format of a batch request [Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch#format-of-a-batch-request)

```
// method id "compute.disks.delete":

type DisksDeleteCall struct {
    s          *Service
    project    string
    zone       string
    disk       string
    urlParams_ gensupport.URLParams
    ctx_       context.Context
    header_    http.Header
}

// Delete: Deletes the specified persistent disk. Deleting a disk
// removes its data permanently and is irreversible. However, deleting a
// disk does not delete any snapshots previously made from the disk. You
// must separately delete snapshots.
// For details, see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/disks/delete
func (r *DisksService) Delete(project string, zone string, disk string) *DisksDeleteCall {
    c := &DisksDeleteCall{s: r.s, urlParams_: make(gensupport.URLParams)}
    c.project = project
    c.zone = zone
    c.disk = disk
    return c
}

// RequestId sets the optional parameter "requestId": An optional
// request ID to identify requests. Specify a unique request ID so that
// if you must retry your request, the server will know to ignore the
// request if it has already been completed.
//
// For example, consider a situation where you make an initial request
// and the request times out. If you make the request again with the
// same request ID, the server can check if original operation with the
// same request ID was received, and if so, will ignore the second
// request. This prevents clients from accidentally creating duplicate
// commitments.
//
// The request ID must be a valid UUID with the exception that zero UUID
// is not supported (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000).
func (c *DisksDeleteCall) RequestId(requestId string) *DisksDeleteCall {
    c.urlParams_.Set("requestId", requestId)
    return c
}

// Fields allows partial responses to be retrieved. See
// https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/basics#PartialResponse
// for more information.
func (c *DisksDeleteCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *DisksDeleteCall {
    c.urlParams_.Set("fields", googleapi.CombineFields(s))
    return c
}

// Context sets the context to be used in this call's Do method. Any
// pending HTTP request will be aborted if the provided context is
// canceled.
func (c *DisksDeleteCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *DisksDeleteCall {
    c.ctx_ = ctx
    return c
}

// Header returns an http.Header that can be modified by the caller to
// add HTTP headers to the request.
func (c *DisksDeleteCall) Header() http.Header {
    if c.header_ == nil {
        c.header_ = make(http.Header)
    }
    return c.header_
}

func (c *DisksDeleteCall) doRequest(alt string) (*http.Response, error) {
    reqHeaders := make(http.Header)
    for k, v := range c.header_ {
        reqHeaders[k] = v
    }
    reqHeaders.Set("User-Agent", c.s.userAgent())
    var body io.Reader = nil
    c.urlParams_.Set("alt", alt)
    c.urlParams_.Set("prettyPrint", "false")
    urls := googleapi.ResolveRelative(c.s.BasePath, "{project}/zones/{zone}/disks/{disk}")
    urls += "?" + c.urlParams_.Encode()
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("DELETE", urls, body)
    req.Header = reqHeaders
    googleapi.Expand(req.URL, map[string]string{
        "project": c.project,
        "zone":    c.zone,
        "disk":    c.disk,
    })
    return gensupport.SendRequest(c.ctx_, c.s.client, req)
}

// Do executes the "compute.disks.delete" call.
// Exactly one of *Operation or error will be non-nil. Any non-2xx
// status code is an error. Response headers are in either
// *Operation.ServerResponse.Header or (if a response was returned at
// all) in error.(*googleapi.Error).Header. Use googleapi.IsNotModified
// to check whether the returned error was because
// http.StatusNotModified was returned.
func (c *DisksDeleteCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error) {
    gensupport.SetOptions(c.urlParams_, opts...)
    res, err := c.doRequest("json")
    if res != nil && res.StatusCode == http.StatusNotModified {
        if res.Body != nil {
            res.Body.Close()
        }
        return nil, &googleapi.Error{
            Code:   res.StatusCode,
            Header: res.Header,
        }
    }
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer googleapi.CloseBody(res)
    if err := googleapi.CheckResponse(res); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    ret := &Operation{
        ServerResponse: googleapi.ServerResponse{
            Header:         res.Header,
            HTTPStatusCode: res.StatusCode,
        },
    }
    target := &ret
    if err := gensupport.DecodeResponse(target, res); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return ret, nil
    // {
    //   "description": "Deletes the specified persistent disk. Deleting a disk removes its data permanently and is irreversible. However, deleting a disk does not delete any snapshots previously made from the disk. You must separately delete snapshots.",
    //   "httpMethod": "DELETE",
    //   "id": "compute.disks.delete",
    //   "parameterOrder": [
    //     "project",
    //     "zone",
    //     "disk"
    //   ],
    //   "parameters": {
    //     "disk": {
    //       "description": "Name of the persistent disk to delete.",
    //       "location": "path",
    //       "required": true,
    //       "type": "string"
    //     },
    //     "project": {
    //       "description": "Project ID for this request.",
    //       "location": "path",
    //       "pattern": "(?:(?:[-a-z0-9]{1,63}\\.)*(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?):)?(?:[0-9]{1,19}|(?:[a-z0-9](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?))",
    //       "required": true,
    //       "type": "string"
    //     },
    //     "requestId": {
    //       "description": "An optional request ID to identify requests. Specify a unique request ID so that if you must retry your request, the server will know to ignore the request if it has already been completed.\n\nFor example, consider a situation where you make an initial request and the request times out. If you make the request again with the same request ID, the server can check if original operation with the same request ID was received, and if so, will ignore the second request. This prevents clients from accidentally creating duplicate commitments.\n\nThe request ID must be a valid UUID with the exception that zero UUID is not supported (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000).",
    //       "location": "query",
    //       "type": "string"
    //     },
    //     "zone": {
    //       "description": "The name of the zone for this request.",
    //       "location": "path",
    //       "pattern": "[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?",
    //       "required": true,
    //       "type": "string"
    //     }
    //   },
    //   "path": "{project}/zones/{zone}/disks/{disk}",
    //   "response": {
    //     "$ref": "Operation"
    //   },
    //   "scopes": [
    //     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    //     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute"
    //   ]
    // }

}
```

Comment: Question is, how to get the HTTP requests out of the go client library. I could only find the `.Do()` functions like `client.Zones.List("project").Do()` which assemble the HTTP request, send it, wait for a response, decode it, etc. Maybe you can write a custom `http.Client` and hand it over to the client lib; you'd have to run each request of the batch asynchronously in its own goroutine...

Comment: To clarify this a bit: My question is *not* how to perform batch requests to the GCP APIs. That is documented. My question is how to perform batch requests using the *Google API Client Library for Go*.

Comment: did you try using [sling](https://github.com/dghubble/sling) or [resty](https://github.com/go-resty/resty) library?

Comment: Nope, but as far as I can see they only get me there part of the way. The main work is to define the structs (e.g. which fields are required/expected) and the protocol (e.g. the request returns an operation ID which I need to use in another request to get the status). That's what the *Google API Client Library for Go* does for me: it gives me static types for the messages and implements large parts of the protocol. I'd like to avoid having to reimplement that.

Comment: I did add the func (DisksDeleteCall) by GO, something that you may be interested

Comment: Well yes, that's part of the Google API Client Library for Go. But despite its name `DisksDeleteCall`, it only allows the deletion of *one* disk at a time. As you can see, the `Do` function (or rather, the `doRequest` function) assembles the request message, but it also sends the request and handles the response. For a batch call, I'd have to either separate those phases (get the request message, glue it to create a batch call, repeat, and finally send the batch request) or hack into the `http.Context` used to send the request in the `Do` function.

Comment: to be honest I used one request call for one disk at time, it's a good approach, looking for your finding.